# Renaming row values with column name and then aggregating it into one column using R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with row values as 0 and 1. Now I need to replace the 1 with column name. Later I need to aggregate them to one column (since there is not duplication in a single row).

The dataframe looks like this one

```
var1   var2    var3 
0      1       0
1      0       0
0      0       1
```

Expected output

```
var1   var2    var3 var
0      var2    0    var2
var1   0       0    var1
0      0       var3 var3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution for an arbitrary data frame and target value:

```
df <- data.frame(
var1  = c(0,1,0),
var2 = c(1,0,0),
var3 = c(0,0,1))

# Task 1 
val <- 1 # value to subsitute
for (n in names(df)){
  df[[n]][df[[n]] == val] <- n
}

# Task 2
df$var <- apply(df, 2, function(x) x[grepl("var", x)])
```

Comment: I could not grasp the function(x) in task 2. Where should I learn about it? Thanks for your solution.

Comment: `apply` with `MARGIN = 2` applies the function I defined row-wise. The function returns an element of a row for which the condition inside the brackets is true. `grepl` will search for a pattern("var") and return TRUE/FALSE. Type  `?apply` and `?grepl` in the R console to learn more.

Comment: I appreciate you for providing an explanation.

Comment: Now I realize the power of the for loop in R. You have provided a wonderful solution. I have changed the accepted answer. Thanks for your answer @slava

Answer (score 1):

[You should try `gather()` from the `tidyr` package.](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html)

Gather will create one column with the var-name and one with the value. Afterwards you can then filter to only value 1 and then drop the value-column.

```
library(dplyr) # for piping
library(tidyr) # for gather

df %>%
gather(var,value) %>% # the arguments simply name the output columns
filter(value == 1) %>%
select(-value)
```

Comment: `gather` did not preserve the row values when it is an `NA`. Also it did not keep the rows intact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `ifelse` statements to replace 1's with the column name.

e.g.

`df$var1 = ifelse(df$var1 == 1, "var1", 0)`

if you want to iterate over multiple columns, you can probably make it more replicable by using `lapply` and a list of column names, and then instead of having "var1" in the `ifelse` statement use `names(df[x])`

Comment: this was quite easy to follow through as a novice programmer.